Difference between regular def and lambda for reversing a url in django test
Consider the following two examples and explain to me why they are different (they look the same to me but the lambda does not work as expected)
Using the lambda, I keep getting the following error:
TypeError: SurveyConversationViewSetTestCase.setUpTestData.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

nested url
/api/surveys/<survey_pk>/survey-conversations/<pk>/ survey_conversations.views.SurveyConversationViewSet    survey-conversations-detail

Test
class SurveyConversationViewSetTestCase(UserSetupMixin, APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super().setUpTestData()

        cls.update_url = lambda self, pk: reverse(
            "survey-conversations-detail", kwargs={"survey_pk": cls.survey.pk, "pk": pk}
        )

    def get_update_url(self, pk):
        return reverse(
            "survey-conversations-detail",
            kwargs={"survey_pk": self.survey.pk, "pk": pk},
        )


    # this fails
    def test_with_lambda(self):
        response_create = self.client.post(
            self.create_url, {"participant_id": self.participant.pk}
        )
        conversation_id = response_create.data["conversation_id"]
        self.client.patch(self.update_url(str(conversation_id)),{"answer": "Walking"})

    # this passes
    def test_with_def(self):
        response_create = self.client.post(
            self.create_url, {"participant_id": self.participant.pk}
        )
        conversation_id = response_create.data["conversation_id"]
        update_url = self.get_update_url(conversation_id)
        response = self.client.patch(update_url, {"answer": "Walking"}, format="json")



When you refer to an object method, the object in question is bound to the method. This means self gets passed implicitly. However, the lambda does not have any relation to the object so it is equivalent to passing SurveyConversationViewSetTestCase.get_update_url.
